# The instance of entity type X cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id:}' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

i am using entity framework core 7 in my .net 7 project. Here is my update method

```
 public async Task UpdateAsync(int id, SiteDto dto)
    {

        Site site = await _context.Sites.Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Include(x => x.Network)
            .Include (x => x.Centre)
            .Include(x => x.SiteDayParts).ThenInclude(x => x.SiteFrames)
            .Include(x => x.Resolution)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        _mapper.Map(dto, site);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

SiteDto object, context has the same fields

```
public class SiteDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public MediaFormat Formats { get; set; }
    public int ResolutionId { get; set; }
    public List<SiteDayPartDto> SiteDayParts { get; set; }
}



public class SiteDayPartDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public List<SiteFrameDto> SiteFrames { get; set; }
}



public class SiteFrameDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FrameId { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping config

```
CreateMap<SiteDto, Site>();

CreateMap<SiteDayPartDto, SiteDayPart>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.AdLength, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Duration));      

CreateMap<SiteFrameDto, SiteFrame>()
```

When I trying to save changes, I get an error "The instance of entity type 'SiteFrame' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached."
Database - Postgresql.
Context registered as scoped, mapper, as I know, don`t create new object.
It is interesting that, if I use entity framework 6, it works well.

Comment: Have you changed migrations where an id is added?

Comment: Are you registering your repository service as Singleton or Scoped ? Using services.AddScoped<..> might solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, all fields are in the table

Comment: All services are scoped

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the problem like this. First, install Automapper.Collections and add:

```
 services.AddAutoMapper((serviceProvider, automapper) =>
        {
            automapper.AddCollectionMappers();
        }, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Then if you have nested list with a nested list, as in my example, add this mapping:

```
 CreateMap<SiteDayPartDto, SiteDayPart>()
            .EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.Id == o.Id)
CreateMap<SiteFrameDto, SiteFrame>()
            .EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.Id == o.Id)
```

EqualityComparison will check if entity contains dto or not (it may be useful https://github.com/AutoMapper/Automapper.Collection). Good luck!